# Identity Server 4 - ExtensionGrant and TokenValidator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, identityserver4, access-token

My company was in need to have a SSO solution with an external identity provider so I looked up the official documentation and found this: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html

The custom flow I implemented is working and I am able to generate a token based on an incoming JWT token from the external provider. The problem I'm facing is that after implementing the interface **ITokenValidator** and adding it to DI (as said in the documentation page) every standard flow started using that custom validator so all other application directly connected to my IDS4 solution were throwing errors of type "Signature validation failed. Unable to match key" on the login phase.

I immediately thought that the problem was coming from my Custom Validator because in that flow I use a public key to validate the token. After discovering this, I removed the dependency injection line of the custom validator from the Startup class and all my standard flow were working again while my custom one wasn't because it was using the default Token Validator at that point (and it's not good enough for my purpose).

My guess is that by adding the custom validator to DI it then overrides the default one that should instead be used by all other standard flow.

I added DI for the ExtensionGrant in this way

```
services.AddIdentityServer((identityServerOptions) =>
    {
         identityServerOptions.InputLengthRestrictions.Scope = scopeInputLength;
         identityServerOptions.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
         identityServerOptions.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
         identityServerOptions.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
         identityServerOptions.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
     })
     .AddSigningCredential(signatureCertificate)
     .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
     .AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
     .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
     .AddExtensionGrantValidator<DelegationGrantValidator>()
      // This one
     .AddExtensionGrantValidator<CustomGrantValidator>()
     .AddResourceStore<ResourceStore>();
```

and for the token validator this way

```
services.AddTransient<ITokenValidator, CustomValidator>();
```

**EDIT**: If I don't use Dependency Injection but instead I do this

```
await new CustomValidator().ValidateAccessTokenAsync(userToken);
```

Default and custom grant works. Am I missing something like giving the application access to the public key to decrypt the token being passed in this flow?

Is there a work around for this? Maybe I should implement a different interface for the token validator? I can't find more docs on this. Plase help me troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by not using an implementation of `ITokenValidator`.

Apparently if you implement this interface or even `ICustomTokenValidator` it will override defaults one and if there are different keys to encrypt/decrypt the access token being passed this causes problem with other flow